# Determine Android version on a device that is stuck on lock screen and with FRP

Tags: locked-out, android-versions

On my Motorola Moto E6 (XT2005-5) that is locked with a PIN I don't have and also with FRP, does "surfna9" mean it is Android 9? If not, where do I look without the PIN to know what version is installed?

Comment: According to some online database the xt2005-5 was shipped with Android 9. If it has received an update to Android 10 I don't know.

Comment: you can read properties via [fastboot](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-releases-separate-adb-and-fastboot-binary-downloads) commands in fastboot [mode](https://www.hardreset.info/devices/motorola/motorola-moto-e6/fastboot-mode): *'fastboot getvar ro.build.fingerprint'* *'fastboot getvar ro.build.version.full'* *'fastboot getvar version-baseband'* *'fastboot getvar kernel.version'*

Comment: `fastboot getvar all` is another quick way to see all available variables on your device. I am assuming FRP prevents you from getting to recovery since that is where data can be reset. My Android version was shown there.